# Getting Error while trying to save file in a folder in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Folder Structure

```
Project_Folder -|
                 Scripts-|
                          images -|
                          file.py
```

Inside `file.py`

```
import requests
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
url = "http://d2np4vr8r37sds.cloudfront.net/800313-kkenlukmjy-1481094947.jpg"
image = requests.get(url)
IMG_DIR = 'images'
IMG_DIR_ABS = os.path.join('.', IMG_DIR)
filename = "800313-kkenlukmjy-1481094947.jpg"
fullfilename = os.path.join(IMG_DIR_ABS, filename)
with open(fullfilename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(image.content)
    f.close()
```

When I am running this code I am getting following error

```
python scripts/file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/file.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(fullfilename, 'wb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './images/800313-kkenlukmjy-1481094947.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IMG_DIR_ABS = os.path.join('.', IMG_DIR)` does not resolve the location of the current script. `.` is the current directory, not the directory of the current script.

What you want to do is:

```
IMG_DIR_ABS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), IMG_DIR)
```

`__file__` being the full filepath of the currently running script, which matches your expectations given your directory tree.

the advantage of this method is that you can launch your script from any directory.

Aside: no need for `f.close()` within the `with` block. `with` context handles that for you when exiting the block.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your script from `Project_Folder`, but there is no such path `'./images/800313-kkenlukmjy-1481094947.jpg'` if You look from that directory. Try using `'./scripts/images/800313-kkenlukmjy-1481094947.jpg'` instead.